# how to install NGM.Forum module in Orchard CMS V1.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, orchardcms

How we can install `NGM.Forum` module In `Orchard CMS` version 1.5?
the problem is that `NGM.Forum` has used `RoutePart` but as you know since Orchard version 1.4 the `RoutePar`t is obsoleted and now we don't have definatiion for `RoutePart` in version 1.5.

Do you know any way to resolve and use it?

with many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently in the process of rewriting it to work on the newer version of Orchard.

There were alot of hacks in the early version where it was a proof of concept.

Please go to http://orchardforums.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets Clone the Repo and update to the tip of Default

Nick

Comment: Actually, it is not work. I tried it with 1.5.1 and 1.6 RC. Can you provide manual how I can install your Forums module on a orchard.
I can't do it with any version of Orchard.

Comment: in visual studio i ran it in debugging mode but when i uploaded it to host it didn't work. i guess the lake of Taxonomy and Vote components may cause the problem. because at the beginning of the debug it couldn't resolve them, so i located in solution and resolved them.

Comment: Fantastic. I though Orchard stopped you enabling modules where the dependencies didnt exist.. odd!

Answer (score 1):

The module is being rewritten according to http://orchardforums.codeplex.com/workitem/14.

Download the lastest source from the [Codeplex page](http://orchardforums.codeplex.com) and try it out, it doesn't depend on Routable anymore.